# Migration request

Tags: support, questions, site-content, moderators, migration

Some time ago, I asked [How can one redirect to a new host all traffic destined for an old host?](https://serverfault.com/q/677357) on ServerFault.  Alas, I never received a satisfactory response.

With hindsight, I’m not too sure why I didn’t ask it on NetworkEngineering.  Would this site like to have it?  If so, could a mod request migration please?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations are off-topic here. Basically, you want to NAT on the destination address.

Comment: As it stands, Ron is correct. However, if rewritten looking for a network based solution, it could probably work.

Comment: Thanks.   I was quite specifically looking for host configuration, so I guess it’s OT here.  No worries!